# Contacted by recruiter on work address

Tags: recruitment, email

I have received an email from a recruiter on my current company email. I am curious how they came across the address, because I only use it for internal communication and company-related accounts, so it should not be publicly available.

What would be a good way to ask the recruiter how they found my email?

Thank you.

Comment: What would you do with that information?

Comment: @Sneftel I would like to prevent unwanted communication on a company email.

Comment: Then get a good spam filter. Over the last several decades, it has become clear that attempting to keep email addresses secret is not an effective way to prevent unwanted communication.

Comment: Your employer probably already has a spam filter. For example, if using Outlook, you'd look in Junk. In Junk you'll sometimes find things falsely marked as Junk that you want. Outlook has a "Not spam" option in that case. Whether the email is in junk or not, remember not to click on attachments automatically and be sure you are aware of phishing attacks from external emails.

Comment: I really don't think this is a useful question to have.

Comment: The easiest way this happened is that your company name was picked from one of your social network accounts and then attached to a variation of your first and last names that would be picked from the same social network. So for example in some work related social network you have found John Doe that is working at ACME Cool Tech Company that has website acme-ct.com. Now you can send emails to john.doe@acme-ct.com, jdoe@acme-ct.com and john@acme-ct.com and there is a good chance that one of these emails would work. Whether this is an attacker or incompetent recruiter is for you to decide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is best to not respond at all, but to forward to IS security.  This could be a phishing email, and you do not want to confirm that this is an active email.

Many **CRIMINAL** hackers will do phishing sweeps like this in order to confirm the formatting of corporate emails, then start targeting executives.  The purposes can be as innocuous as poaching employees, to more sinister motives.

Even if it **seems** to come from a real person, the headers could be forged.  the purpose of a phishing expedition like this could be to get the format of the corporate emails, then forge an email from an executive.  It's been done.  I don't want to give too many details, because then this will be come an instructional post on how to scam.

**FORWARD TO IS SECURITY**

Never open unsolicited, external emails.

Comment: Thank you. While it could be a phishing attempt, the author is an actual person, I have checked.

Comment: @RomiHalasz The values in a mail-header (recipient, mail-name-rewrite, relay-domain, relay-address etc. ) can easily be generated/manipulated.. I could send you an email from miles.davis@jazz.org immediately - but that doesn't mean I'm Miles Davis.. ;)

Comment: Hackers are actual people. Pentesters are actual people. Being an actual person doesn't make you legitimate. This answer is so correct and complete that it shouldn't even need to be said out loud. +1

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming your company email is:

> Romi.Halasz@companyname.com

Or something along those lines... The exact format will be easy enough to find on the company website and then all someone needs to do is swap out the beginning for the name of whoever they want to contact from that company.

You may think this is a lot of effort, but it's pretty easy and they probably emailed a handful of people from the same company, just taking the name off LinkedIn or the company website and adding it to that email template.

You'll get this happening occasionally - I do. Sometimes you'll get a sales pitch too, this is usually sent out to everyone they can find, just hoping one sticks!

Best thing you can do is block the address.

---

I have assumed you've checked all the obvious places like the company website and ensured there is no externally shared directory? You can always check with IT if this becomes an issue.

Comment: I do think it's a lot of effort for one particular email, but if you want to send a message to multiple employees, then I can see it working.

Comment: If someone did want to get hold of you though I think it's about the same effort as going and finding your email elsewhere online. Recruiters are very insistent in getting in touch with someone they think they can temp into a new role

Comment: *I do think it's a lot of effort for one particular email* what if the recruiter has software that automatically scrapes prospective names, pings email servers until it gets one to go through, and then sends emails matching that format to the whole list of candidates at that employer? Then it's pretty much zero effort. The actual human recruiter just sits back and waits for people to reply.